# Using controller inside repeat, do I need a directive?

Tags: angularjs

When using a ng-repeat, how should I use a controller inside it?

For example, if I'm looping over a set of days in a week:

```html
<ul ng-controller="WeekCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="d in days">
        <span ng-controller="DayCtrl">
            {{dayOfWeek}} {{date}}: {{info}}
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But my `DayCtrl` wants to know what day `d` it is, so has to pull that out of the scope:

```js
app.controller('DayCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.date = $scope.d.date;
  $scope.dayOfWeek = 
    ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thr','Fri','Sat','Sun']
    [$scope.d.date.getDay()];
  $scope.info = '... extra info...';
});
```

But this creates a dependency between the display and the controller. Ideally, I'd like to pass in `d.date` as an argument.

I could write a directive+controller and pass `d.date` in as an attribute. But that means I have to write a lot more and move the day's html into separate template, and I don't intend to use the DayCtrl elsewhere.

Alternatively, I could try and use `<span ng-init="date=d.date">` but again, this feels dirty.

What's the right way of doing this.

Full example code on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wUxNFSEGjcDN7KlOLYdv which shows the problem I'm having with days and weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this seems like a job for a directive, with `d.date` specified as an attribute.
  I don't know how `info` is populated, but potentially your directive would not need a controller.

The day's HTML doesn't have to be in a separate/directive template, it can remain in the HTML:

```
 <li ng-repeat="d in days">
    <day date="d.date">
       {{dayOfWeek}} {{date}}: {{info}}
    </day>
 </li>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('day', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { date: '=' },
    link: function(scope) {
     scope.dayOfWeek =  ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thr','Fri','Sat','Sun'][scope.date.getDay()];
     scope.info = '... extra info...';
    }
  };
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnQanWa3DT2LsY02BT7X?p=preview).

FYI, if you want to use ng-init, you can include it with the ng-controller:

```
<span ng-controller="DayCtrl" ng-init="date=d.date">
```

Comment: OK. I didn't realise that if you don't include a `template`, then the `link` function gets the `scope` which is available to the inner html. Adding `transclude: true, template: '{{info}}<div ng-transclude></div>',` breaks your example; that that's ok for my needs.